# gameDisplay.fill not filling

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

After experimenting with pygame, I have tried to start a new code for a new game. I want to fill in the background with a colour (right now just a purple-red color for testing). I have experimented with moving `gameDisplay.fill` in and out of loops and functions but all of them just lead to an empty display (empty grey screen) and it keeps loding. What is wrong with my code here?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 1440
displayHeight = 900
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Grow')
color = (200, 0, 150)
play = True

def gameLoop():
    gameDisplay.fill(color)

gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update the display. Without updating, the changes won't be shown.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 1440
displayHeight = 900
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Grow')
color = (200, 0, 150)
play = True

def gameLoop():
    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.display.update()

gameloop()
```